# Configure ipaddress with systemd-networkd without link

Tags: systemd, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I am running debian (testing) with systemd v234. I decided to give systemd-networkd a shot for my network configuration. 
Wifi configuration with dhcp form my router worked well thanks to the [Arch-Linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd).

I have a local ethernet interface (`enp0s31f6`)  I use for development of embedded systems that get served IP-addresses from a dhcp-server on my computer that is bound to `enp0s31f6` and serves from a a small pool of ip addresses.
The problem is, the dhcp server does not start if the `enp0s31f6` has not ip address at boot time. `enp0s31f6` **only gets configured with an ip address if it has link**, i.e. if I start my computer with a powered embedded system connected on `enp0s31f6`.

Here is my configuration in `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s31f6.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s31f6
[Network]
IPForward=yes
Domains=embedded.loc
[Address]
Address=192.168.0.1/24
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.0.1
Destination=192.168.0.0/24
```

**How do I make systemd-netword configure my interface with an ip address even if there is no link?**

(basically the the way it used to be with `/etc/network/interfaces`?)